# Divergence of $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k$ - is this the reason?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I don't really get why 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k$$
diverges, as it is simply
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1...,$$
which makes it $0$.

However, if we calculate some partial sums:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2}(-1)^k = 1 - 1 +1 = 1$$
$$\sum_{k = 3}^{5}(-1)^k = -1 + 1 -1 = 0$$
*(Well, $-1 + 1 - 1$ is obviously not $0$, so this is just me trying to do calculus without knowing how to add and subtract numbers. Anyways, I'm going to leave it for the question's sake).*
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{5}(-1)^k = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 =0$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2}(-1)^k + \sum_{k = 3}^{5}(-1)^k \neq \sum_{k = 0}^{5}(-1)^k$$

Perhaps this is the problem? 
Because if we do the same with a series that is convergent:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{4} = \frac{56}{32}$$
$$\sum_{k = 3}^{5}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^k = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} = \frac{7}{32}$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{5}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^k = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} = \frac{63}{32}$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k + \sum_{k = 3}^{5}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{5}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$

I admit that the fact that the partial sums do not add up to a numbers that would be logical is fishy, but I still can't really grasp why $1 - 1 + 1 -1 + 1 -1... \neq 0$.

Thanks.

Comment: $-1+1-1=-1{}$...

Comment: What a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A series is convergent iff the sequence of its partial sums converges.

The sequence of partial sums of your serie is $$\{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots\}$$ and this sequence is clearly not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

"which makes it $0$": no.

The partial sums are

$$1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,\cdots$$

which is obviously not a converging sequence.

---

Also note that following your logics,

$$-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$$ should be $0$.

And what about

$$1+(-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-\cdots)\ ?$$

Answer (score 2):

The series is known as [**Grandi's series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) which diverges in the usual sense and definition but it converges to $\frac12$ according to [**Cesaro summation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

Answer (score 1):

When you add an even number of terms you get $0$ and when you add an odd number of terms you get $1$

You can not have two different numbers as your sum so we mark it as divergent, simpy because it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

> ... as it is simply
>   $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots,$$
>   which makes it $0$.

**No.** In the case of an *infinite* sum, familiar rules for *finite* sums might fail. In your case, informally, there are two simple ways to add paratheses that would give you two different answers:

$$
\begin{align}
[1+(-1)]+[1+(-1)]+\cdots = 0\tag{1a}\\
1+[(-1)+1]+[(-1)+1]+\cdots = 1\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$

The mathematical expression $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is **defined** as the limit (when exists) of the "partial sums":
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\tag{2}
$$ 
where $S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. When (1) does not exist, we say that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is divergent.

In your case, $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k$ and the limit of the sequence of partial sums $(S_{n})_{n=0}^\infty$ does not exist. Why? One of the necessary conditions for a convergence sequence is that all the convergent subsequences must have the same limit. But here we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} S_{2n}=0,\tag{3}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} S_{2n+1}=1.\tag{4}
$$

Note that (3) and (4) are the corresponding rigorous ways to talk about (1a) and (1b) respectively.

---

The reason you found
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2}(-1)^k + \sum_{k = 3}^{5}(-1)^k \neq \sum_{k = 0}^{5}(-1)^k$$
is that you did it in a wrong way:
$$
\sum_{k = 3}^{5}(-1)^k=-1\neq 0.
$$